# Stumped by simple C++ multiple-inheritance example

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I've been looking at C++ Core Guidelines item [C.129](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-kind) and copy-pasted a multiple inheritance example, but can't figure out why both MS compiler and CLang show me the same error... It's gotta be something awfully simple!

The code:

```
    class Shape { // pure interface
    public:
        virtual void draw() = 0;
    };
    class Circle : public Shape { // pure interface
    public:
        virtual int radius() = 0;
    };

    class Shape_Impl : public Shape {
    public:
        void draw() override {}
    };
    class Circle_Impl : public Shape_Impl, public Circle {
    public:
        int radius() override { return 42; }
    };

    int main()
    {
        Circle_Impl* ic = new Circle_Impl();
        return 0;
    }
```

Why does instantiation of `Circle_Impl` fail with "unimplemented pure virtual method 'draw' in 'Circle_Impl'" error? Hasn't `draw` implementation been defined in `Shape_Impl`???

Comment: Because there are *two* `Shape`s in that `Circle_Impl`, and only one of them has an implementation of `draw()` (provided by `Shape_Impl`).

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you forgot the `virtual` keyword when inheriting from `Shape` which declares the pure virtual method `draw`:

```
class Circle : public virtual Shape { ...
class Shape_Impl : public virtual Shape { ...
```

without the `virtual` keyword you get duplicated base instances, which results in the wrong things happening.  In general, if you want multiple inheritance when you might inherit the same class via mulitple inheritance chains, you need `virtual` to make it work properly.

Comment: Reverted my downvote, I thought you were talking about the function prototype. It would be good to outline *what* that `virtual` does though.

Comment: Surprisingly, adding `virtual` in the two lines Chris suggested worked...
I thought that making inheritance virtual was only needed, if super-classes had data members and could be omitted for interface classes. Apparently, I was wrong...
    

MS compiler produced C4250 warning "'Circle_Impl': inherits 'Shape_Impl::Shape_Impl::draw' via dominance", which I will look up in a sec, while CLang was quiet.

Comment: @Boris: Without the `virtual` keyword, you get "C++ inheritance" which is only vaguely similar to "inheritance" in the normal computer science definition of the term.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use virtual inheritance. Without it, your class hierarchy looks roughly like this:

```
Shape       Shape  <-- Two Shape instances, each requiring its own draw() implementation
  |           |
  |         Circle
  |           |
Shape_Impl    |
  |           |    <-- draw() not implemented in the right-hand branch
   \         /
   Circle_Impl
```

Using virtual inheritance, this is what it looks like:

```
     Shape     <- Single Shape instance, requiring only a single implementation of draw()
   /       \
  |         |
  |       Circle
  |         |
Shape_Impl  |
  |         |
   \       /
  Circle_Impl
```

To use virtual inheritance, simply append the keyword `virtual` before inheriting:

```
class Circle : public virtual Shape
class Shape_Impl : public virtual Shape
```

Comment: Looks like Chris came up with a much better worded [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48407711/3854787) before I finished this :D. I took too long to "draw" the ugly ASCII diagrams. I'll keep this answer here, though, in case it helps to better visualize the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Hasn't `draw` implementation been defined in `Shape_Impl`?

It hasn't been implemented in the `Circle` branch of the inheritance hierarchy.

You'll need something along the lines of:

```
class Circle_Impl : public Shape_Impl, public Circle {
public:
    void draw() override { Shape_Impl::draw(); }
    int radius() override { return 42; }
};
```

Comment: There should be no need to re-implement `draw()` in `Circle_impl`, as its implementation ought to be inherited from `Shape_Impl`, who is one of the super-classes of `Circle_impl`...
Isn't this the point of multiple inheritance?

Comment: @Boris, that simple logic doesn't work with multiple inheritance. You might want to read up on "virtual inheritance in C++".